# Logstash - if condition ignored

Tags: parsing, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am struggling with an issue, that my if condition is completely ignored by logstash.
It is nothing complicated, but yet I can't see my tags added to the event.

```
if [records][properties][resourceDisplayName] =~ /Windows Azure Active Directory/ {
    mutate {
      remove_tag => [ "Windows" ]
      add_tag => [ "Azure" ]
    }
  }

  if [records][properties][resourceDisplayName] =~ /Outlook/ {
    mutate {
      remove_tag => [ "Windows" ]
      add_tag => [ "Outlook" ]
    }
  }
```

Tags "Azure" and "Outlook" are not added at all and tag "Windows" is still available.
I have tried also like this:

```
if "Outlook" in [records][properties][resourceDisplayName] {
 do something
}
```

and this

```
if [records][properties][resourceDisplayName] == "Outlook" { 
  do something 
}
```

But it didn't work either.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely [records][properties][resourceDisplayName] does not exist, perhaps one of the fields is an array. What does the data structure look like if you use `output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }`

Comment: There is "records.properties.resourceDisplayName" field and i tried also making a condition with dots, but didnt work either...

Comment: check if [records][properties][resourceDisplayName] is nested field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was an array.
This worked for me.

```
if [records][0][properties][resourceDisplayName]
```